# Add a new column in array with a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm using an API to retrieve data on some stocks and I would like to add a column named `symbol` with the `query` values but I'm getting an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['` in `this.result.[i].push...`. Is there any other way to do call the i-th element and pass the query data or is the syntax just wrong?

The rest of the code is just me saving the output as CSV file

This is the code:

```
import ObjectsToCsv from 'objects-to-csv';
import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2';

async function api(){

  const query = 'TSLA';
  const queryOptions = { period1: '2021-08-06', interval: "1d"};
  let result = await yahooFinance.historical(query, queryOptions);

  function insertColumn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.result.length; i++) {
      this.result.[i].push({symbol: query}); // in this line I'm getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['" in `this.result.[i].push...`
    }
  };

  console.log(result);

  (async () => {
    const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(result);
    await csv.toDisk('C:/Users/Rafael Oliveira/Desktop/teste/test.csv');
  })();
};
api();
```

Thank you in advance, any help is welcome (if you have any other method to add a new column like {symbol: query} instead of the one I'm using feel free to share as well!}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for that dot before the array indexation.

```js
this.result.[i] // Bad
this.result[i] // Good
```

To fix the other errors:

```js
import ObjectsToCsv from 'objects-to-csv';
import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2';

async function api(){

  const query = 'TSLA';
  const queryOptions = { period1: '2021-08-06', interval: "1d"};
  let result = await yahooFinance.historical(query, queryOptions);

  const insertColumn = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      result[i].push({symbol: query});
    }
  };
  insertColumn();

  console.log(result);

  (async () => {
    const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(result);
    await csv.toDisk('C:/Users/Rafael Oliveira/Desktop/teste/test.csv');
  })();
};
api();
```

Declaring `insertColumn` this way, you're capturing `result` inside a closure. Another option is to bind the original function declaration with `this` and declaring the result variable as `this.result` instead of `let result`.

```js
this.result = await yahooFinance.historical(query, queryOptions);

  function insertColumn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.result.length; i++) {
      this.result[i].push({symbol: query});
    }
  };
 insertColumn.call(this)
```

Check out MDN for more information:

- [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)
- [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thank you, that removed the error, but the column hasn't been added still

Comment: You're not calling the function insertColumn, you're just declaring insertColumn. Try invoking it: insertColumn();

Comment: When I call the function insertColumn I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined`

Comment: Thank you for providing the sources as well! I'm still getting the same Type error, however. I'll search a bit for the asnwer before posting another query, thank you!